# What is Google Authenticator's app style called and where can I get more visual resources?

Tags: layout

I love the UI of the Google Authenticator, and I am currently in the design phase of my Team Fortress 2 Server Status application. I am looking to have each server as a "card" much like Authenticator has and a sparkline for the number of players across the day.

What is Google Authenticator's UI style and where can I get more resources on staying consistent to the style here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google utilizes the [FlatUI](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/) trend, then the "cards" mechanism is something they brought in with Google NOW and are rolling out across their platform to distinguish content on their dashboard like applications.

Comment: My God this is absolutely perfect! Are there any Android libraries (my app is Android) to leverage anything Google has already existing so I don't have to write them from scratch?

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI

Comment: There you go! Kindly mark as answered ;)